# SQL to Excel - ODBC vs. POI

Tags: excel, odbc, apache-poi, adodb

I want to export data (~10.000 entries) to excel and I am not sure which technology to choose. Apache POI looks quite nice to me. Can anybody give information about the differences in performance when processing the code.

(A) PHP7 & OBDC / ADOdb

(B) Java & Apache POI

What would you recommend to use?

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer PHP or Java, I would choose between:

(A) PHP & PHPExcel
or
(B) Java & Apache POI

You should do performance tests and choose the best that fits you. The results may vary and depends by your data. You will also need to do optimizations.